# Sendbird Chat React Total number of channels with unread messages React + Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sendbird

I want to implement a hook to update my view with unread messages count without constantly making a request to the server to get the total number of channels with unread messages with this [request](https://sendbird.com/docs/chat/v3/platform-api/user/managing-unread-count/view-number-of-channels-with-unread-messages) . I am using React + Next.js, I can't seem to find any documentation on how to get into the channels unread messages properties via sdk or `<ChannelList />` ui component. Sendbird support is practically useless, if anyone knows please help

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer, I work for Sendbird*.

When utilizing the UIKit, you'll need to access the underlying SDK instance in order to utilize methods like `getTotalUnreadMessageCount()` or `getTotalUnreadChannelCount()`. First you'll need to get an instance of the current context which can be obtained by calling `useSendbirdStateContext()` which can be imported from `sendbird-uikit`. Note that this does need to be called within a component that is wrapped in the `SendBirdProvider` HOC.

```
const context = useSendbirdStateContext();
const sdkInstance = sendBirdSelectors.getSdk(context);
```

I created an example of this for you on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/usesendbirdstatecontext-example-s8eful

Comment: Wow, Thanks so much for the answer. But I'm now having ```SendBirdException: Command received no ack.``` Error, I am using Next.js and Sendbird UI Kit v2. And also ```SendBirdException: QueryInProgress ``` when scrolling through list of users, is there any way I can fix it, if not how can I at least handle the exceptions so it won't break my app on client side. I see people are also facing the same issue [in community](https://community.sendbird.com/t/sendbird-uikit-react-v2-with-nextjs-error-command-received-no-ack/5025)

Comment: You can even see the error in your [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/usesendbirdstatecontext-example-s8eful) example above

Comment: @AbdulrahimIliasu As you’ve seen on the community, the team is already investigating. I’d follow the community thread you commented on for further updates.

Comment: This solution does not work anymore @TylerHammer

Comment: @LuisContreras Unfortunately, it'll be hard to troubleshoot in stack overflow comments with the amount of data/questions needing answering. I would suggest heading over to the Sendbird community to get more detailed help.